# In a microservice-based app with a premium user with paid subscription model, should the subscription info be stored in a separate microservice?

Tags: rest, architecture, microservices

I'm designing a microservice-based architecture for an existing monolithic app. The database has a User table, and then a separate Subscription database storing subscription info for premium, subscribed users.

My initial idea was to do something like User Service <-> Subscription Service <-> Payment Service. But a colleague believes that the subscription service is unnecessary and can just be merged with the User Service. What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is analogue with the choosing bounded context boundaries problem in DDD. Choosing bounded context can be done with context mapping: https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping/ As far as I remember another approach is imagining the organization which does the same job manually what you automate with your services and check what departments it should have. The usual example is a webshop for this where for example security, shopping, storage, invoicing, delivery, support can go in different services. All of them have user and some of them has product, but they watch these things from different viewpoints, e.g. in the shopping context the product is something that you have in the catalogue and what the customers choose to add to their basket, for invoicing it is an item in the order with a certain price at the moment of the ordering, for storage it is something that must be found in the physical world, probably has a container number, for delivery it is part of a package and must be delivered to an address. Many times a lot of properties are just copy-paste with different property names in these bounded contexts and the DRY principle is not met. So if the reason why your colleague wants to merge them is meeting the DRY principle, then it does not matter. If they belong together logically and in a real company a single department would do them, then they can be merged. There is not much detail in your question, but I think I would separate the subscription service too and I guess I would rename the user service to security if all it does is registration and handling logins and authorization. If it contains something else too, then it is better to check the boundaries, maybe some of the properties belong to a different service, maybe there is another service which does not exist yet.

Another practical aspect is scalability. You can wait until certain parts of a single service is used a lot more than other parts and think about splitting because of scalability reasons.

Another analogy is choosing class size in OOP. Some people claim the smaller the better, but everybody is comfortable with different class sizes. Of course there are too small classes and overengineering and too big classes, god objects, but there is a range where the class size is acceptable and it depends on the personal taste or convenience which size you choose. I think for microservices this can happen too, so maybe your colleague is just comfortable with bigger services. If you check the name of the technology the service size should be micro. Those this is relative too, micro compared to what...

> In my view a single deployable service should be no bigger than a
> bounded context, but no smaller than an aggregate. I would also
> suggest that it’s better to start with relatively broad service
> boundaries to begin with, refactoring to smaller ones as time goes on.
> Perhaps “micro” is a misleading prefix here. These are not necessarily
> “small” as in “little”. These are services in the classic SOA mould,
> except created with more of an agile mind-set including lightweight
> infrastructure, decentralized governance and greater emphasis on
> automation. Perhaps it’s these more agile aspects of microservice
> design that distinguishes them as opposed to size.

https://www.ben-morris.com/how-big-is-a-microservice/

> A Microservice shall be no larger than that which allows a two-pizza
> team to release a single complete, appropriately sized user story to
> production within a single day.

https://kylegenebrown.medium.com/whats-the-right-size-for-a-microservice-bf1740370d47

> Microservice developers can start wherever it “feels right”, and over
> time split or merge microservices to improve the architecture.
> Although I agree that microservice architectures shouldn’t be carved
> in stone and that there should always be the option of changing
> microservice decomposition, it’d be nice to have more clarity as to
> where a good starting point would be.
>
> Identify critical business transactions that require high performance
> and/or solid data integrity and trace those transactions through the
> microservices in your architecture. If you see problems, consider
> changing microservice boundaries and merging a few microservices
> together, as an option.

https://www.pipservices.org/blog/whats-the-right-size-for-a-microservice